# Amazon RDS: Your connection attempt failed for user 'master' to the MySQL server

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, mysql-workbench, amazon-rds

I am unable to connect to the MySQL Amazon RDS instance I created.

I am following the AWS RDS tutorial to connect and entered:

- The endpoint in the "Host" on the workbench
- Credentials including the username and the password
- Port is set to 3306

I get the error:

> Cannot Connect to Database Server
>
> Your connection attempt failed for user 'master' to the MySQL server at xxxx.rds.amazonaws.com:3306:
>
> Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xxxx.amazonaws.com' (10060)

[image: MySQL Workbench error]
Here is the link to the tutorial i am following [Tutorial on setting up & connecting to Amazon RDS](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/create-mysql-db/)

Comment: PS- I also tried posting my question on the AWS help forum but was unable to do so. Apparently, they make you wait several hours in order to post. :(

Comment: Can you provide a link to the tutorial you used?

Comment: thanks for cleaning up my question @John

Comment: Since the tutorial doesn't exactly specify how to configure the **Security Group**, I'd say that's the first thing you should check.

Comment: Looks like your instance is accessible. But the port is blocked by the subnet group. It is not a good idea to post the DB hostnames to the public.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Things to check:

- Since you are connecting from the Internet, the Amazon RDS database must be launched in a **public subnet**
- When launching the Amazon RDS database, select "**Publicly available**"
- Assign a **Security Group** that permits Inbound traffic on port 3306 from your IP address (or `0.0.0.0/0`, but that is much less secure)

Comment: How do i create a public subnet?

Comment: A public subnet is defined as a subnet that has a Route Table entry that directs traffic for `0.0.0.0/0` to an Internet Gateway. You probably already have a Default VPC that has a Public Subnet in each AZ, so just use that. If you have created your own VPC, then you'll need to check which subnets are public.